# Switch another opened app android

Tags: android

I think we have three apps, and all of them are open and we know the process name. How can I switch from one app to another app, also keeping in mind that another app has opened a intent, and I do not want to go to another app with opening an app launcher, just switching or making another app at front.

I want to make another app on front, for example if Internet is background, I make it at front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the main activity for your applications singleProcess, if the application is already running it will be bring to the front. you can also, implement a custom BroadCastReceiver to start the application using its package name.

Comment: I want to make another app on front , for example if Internet is background , I make it at front .